# Return button id on click - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, closures, dom-events

I am making a program that is supposed to make a column of buttons on load.
After that, on click, it should make new column of buttons and display id of the button that is clicked.

It works fine when it is supposed to make new column of buttons, but it displays id of every button in the column. It even returns me ids of the next column. Ids of the first button columns are displayed on load.

Can someone help me to make it display just the id of the button that is clicked.
Here is the code:

```
<html> <head>
<style>
.addItem {
  width: 80px;
  float: left;} </style>
<script>
var lev = 0; var levmax=5;var some;

function addBu(){
    repeat();
};

function repeat(){
    if(lev<levmax){
        lev++;
        var bo = document.getElementById("kod");
        var di = document.createElement('DIV');
        di.className="addItem";
        for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
            var bu= document.createElement('BUTTON');  
            var te = document.createTextNode('Text');
            var te1 = document.createTextNode(lev.toString());
            var br = document.createElement('BR');
            bu.id=(lev*10+i).toString();
            some=(lev*10+i).toString();         
            bu.addEventListener("click", repeat);
            bu.addEventListener("click" , reply_clickk(some));      
            bu.appendChild(te);
            bu.appendChild(te1);
            di.appendChild(bu);
            di.appendChild(br);     
        }       
        bo.insertBefore(di, bo.childNodes[0]);  
    }   

    function reply_clickk(clicked_id){
        alert(clicked_id);
    };

};
</script>
</head> 
<body id="kod" onload="addBu()">
</body></html>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need some aditional info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you call the event handler and attach its return value to the click event instead of the function.

```
bu.addEventListener("click" , reply_clickk(some));
```

you probably rather want something like this

```
bu.addEventListener("click" , function(e){reply_clickk(e.target.id)});
```

In addition your `some` variable is global; change it to `var some` to be scoped to your function `repeat`

```
var some=(lev*10+i).toString();
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzs8u6jg/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a closure to keep the button id

**Working code**

```js
var lev = 0;
    var levmax = 5;
    var some;

    function addBu() {
      repeat();
    };


    function reply_clickk(clicked_id) {
      alert(clicked_id);
    };

    function repeat() {
      if (lev < levmax) {
        lev++;
        var bo = document.getElementById("kod");
        var di = document.createElement('DIV');
        di.className = "addItem";
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          var bu = document.createElement('BUTTON');
          var te = document.createTextNode('Text');
          var te1 = document.createTextNode(lev.toString());
          var br = document.createElement('BR');
          bu.id = (lev * 10 + i).toString();
          some = (lev * 10 + i).toString();
          bu.addEventListener("click", repeat);
          bu.addEventListener("click", function(some) {
            return function() {
              reply_clickk(some)
            }
          }(some));
          bu.appendChild(te);
          bu.appendChild(te1);
          di.appendChild(bu);
          di.appendChild(br);
        }
        bo.insertBefore(di, bo.childNodes[0]);
      }


    };
```

```css
.addItem {
      width: 80px;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<body id="kod" onload="addBu()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a listener like this:

```
bu.addEventListener("click" , reply_clickk(some));
```

Unfortunately, `reply_clickk(some)` is a function call that returns `undefined`. You have to *defer* the function call, i.e. return another function:

```
function reply_clickk(clicked_id){
    return function () {
        alert(clicked_id);
    };
};
```